# How do I execute two CSS animations at once upon hover of a single div?

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to execute two animations at once upon hover of a single div.

One animation is to scale an image to 50%. The other animation is to scale text from 0-100%, and move it up 10px from its original position.

I have successfully created the animation of the scaling image using the code below, but I am running into problems with coding the text animation.

```
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
```

Here is the working scaling image animation on a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZVScz/

How can I now implement the animation of the text scaling from 0-100% and moving up 10px?

Thank in advance to anyone who is able to help out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [adjacent selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) CSS selector, `elem1 + elem2` where `elem2` is immediately after `elem1` and they have the same parent.

I have implemented something to the effect at http://jsfiddle.net/ZVScz/1/ and you can now adjust the transforms to your liking.

If you have any questions feel free to ask.
Fred

Comment: Thanks Fred. This seems to be working pretty solid. Is there an easy way to keep the font size of the worksText the same size? Right now it shrinks with the scale of the image.

Comment: Just remove the `scale (.5)` from the transform property (line 51) - I was under the impression that you wanted it to scale. Just play around with the transform properties until you are happy (you could also use `top:` or `margin-top:` instead of `translateY` but that's up to you to decide. Maybe mark my answer approved if it worked? Thanks.

Comment: Yep. Removing the scale (.5) did the trick! Thanks, this works flawlessly now.

Comment: One last question. The animation seems to be buggy when you hover over the top of the icon. (Due to the scaling)

See bug here: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cI6IV3VKYB

Is there an easy way to fix this from happening? Perhaps by somehow keeping the hover area 64x64px throughout?

Comment: Never mind @Fred I figured it out. Had to move some things around in the CSS in regard to the parent divs and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using : `#worksContainer:hover #worksText { ... }`

Repleace `...` with the animation you want for the text.